# If I rotate my secret key, should my public key change as well?

Tags: cryptography, cryptocurrency, key-rotation

In the asymmetric encryption, public key and secret key are paired. If I rotate my secret key, does this mean I also generate a new public key.

I ask this question because in crypto world, account address is generated using public key, or public verification key. If I rotate my secret and if my public key changes accordingly, then it follows that my account address should also change. Is this logic valid?

Answer (score 0):

If neither a private key nor a public key is attached to the secret, a key rotation will create a new key pair and attach them to the secret. In essence, a key rotation will generate new keys, re-encrypt all data that was encrypted using the old key by using the new keys, and then delete the old encrypted data and old encrypted key.